# SQL GROUP BY explanation

Tags: sql

So I have been playing around with SQL for a while now, and i can't seem to get the group by function down. For example, I have been using the w3schools online database with SQL, and experimenting with it.
One problem I can't seem to crack is to update the prices of products from the same supplier, and that their sum is some number.

Here is the link to the database: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

So what I came up with was this:

```
    UPDATE Products 
    SET Price=Price*100
    WHERE 47=(SELECT SUM(p.Price) FROM Products p GROUP BY p.SupplierID)
```

It seems to update the whole database. I expected it only to update the prices of the products that belong to the first supplier, as the sum of their prices is 47. I guess I'm making some rookie mistake, but I just can't seem to get it right.

Edit: 
My expected result would be that all rows from table Products who have supplierID=1 would update the price(Although it's not that I'm just aiming at the 1st supplier, but any supplier who's products prices sum up to 47), but what happens is that all the prices get updated, regardless of the supplier or the sum of their prices. But when I change the number from 47, nothing seems to happen.

Comment: How can `47` be equal to a **table** containing multiple rows.

Comment: I think I see your point, I guess I thought that WHERE would check for every row, and when it finds a match to 47, it would do the above mentioned. Any ideas on how I could achieve that?

Comment: what does 47 mean?

Comment: what exactly you want? Show ur table with sample data and output u are expecting

Comment: it would do, if the comparison was being made against rows in your main table, but it can't do it against rows in a subquery. If you want to update all items from the first supplier, just use the SupplierID in the WHERE clause. e.g. `WHERE SupplierID = 1`. Your existing query will effectively resolve to  UPDATE Products 
    SET Price=Price*100
    WHERE 47= 47 (the result of the first row of the subquery). Since 47=47 is always true, then all rows will be updated.

Comment: You do realize that the Sum() function actually sums up all the values in the Price column and returns only the summed up value? I didnt get the reason why you re trying to use the Group by clause here.

Comment: Your statement will fail if you have more then one value for `supplierid` in your table.

Comment: I didnt really understand what you re trying to do here, but try keeping this simple something like WHERE Price = [Some Number] AND SupplierID = [Your Concerned SupplierID]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing query will effectively resolve to

```
UPDATE Products SET Price = Price*100 WHERE 47 = 47
```

47 happens, coincidentally, to be the result of the first row of the subquery. Since `47 = 47` is always true, then all rows will be updated. What you actually want to do is find the SupplierID where the SUM of all the products is 47, and use that in the WHERE clause.

This will do what you want, I think:

```
UPDATE Products 
SET Price = Price*100
WHERE SupplierID IN 
  (SELECT SupplierID 
  FROM Products 
  GROUP BY SupplierID 
  HAVING SUM(Price) = 47)
```

It will update the the price of all rows where the SupplierID matches a SupplierID where the total price of all that supplier's products is equal 47. This could in theory update more than one supplier's prices, if there are two where the total price of their products is 47.

Comment: Good explanation. As OP's subquery can return more than one row (one per supplier),their query should actually fail, but you may be right that their DBMS has a flaw and simply takes the first returned row instead. Your solution with an IN clause is very clear and readable.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much, very interesting solution, simple, but I don't think I would have thought of that. Thanks again.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner the original query does indeed work - you can try it at the W3Schools link provided. Details of the underlying DBMS are not given. If you change the "47" value to something (anything) which doesn't happen to match the first row returned by the subquery, then it simply runs but updates no rows.

Answer (score 2):

You want to update all prices where the supplier's product prices sum up to exactly 47. So make sure the subquery queries the products for the supplier of the product that you are about to update or not, i.e. have a correlated subquery.

```
UPDATE Products p1
SET Price = Price * 100
WHERE 47 = (SELECT SUM(p.Price) FROM Products p2 WHERE p2.SupplierID = p1.SupplierID);
```

For every product (p1) we look up the sum of the supplier's products (p2) and update only if the sum is 47.

Comment: I think this is it, for some reason though, it's showing that there is a mistake at a first row(seems to not allow naming Products p1 in the UPDATE line, seems strange). If I can make it work, i think this will be the part I was missing and failing to understand.

Comment: Strange. What DBMS are you using? (You should tag this always with SQL questions.) A workaround might be not to alias the update table and change to `p2.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID) then.

Comment: Have no clue about DBMS, it's whatever w3school guys set up i guess. Yeah, it worked now then I did the changes you proposed, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The `group by` clause aggregates the rows in your table, keeping one row for each combination of values available in the columns you specify.

In your example you have a table with `product`, `supplier` and `price`; if you `group by supplier`, the resulting dataset will have one row for each value in the `supplier` column.

What happens to the other columns depends on what you specify in your `select` clause. You can ignore or aggregate them.

```
select  supplier, sum(price)
from    Products
group by supplier
```

This will return the sum of the `price` column for each  distinct `supplier`, while the `product` will be ignored.

On these aggregated rows the filtering is done with `having` clause, because the `where` only works on the original (not aggregated) rows.

Going on with the example above, selecting the supplier whose products prices have a sum of 47 would require

```
select  supplier, sum(price)
from    Products
group by supplier
having  sum(price) = 47
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
UPDATE [Products]
SET  [Products].Price = [Products].Price*100
FROM    [Products] 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  p.SupplierID, SUM(p.Price) NewPrice
                    FROM Products p 
                    GROUP BY p.SupplierID) B
        ON B.SupplierID = [Products].SupplierID
WHERE 47 = B.NewPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an inner join, to join the sums back to the table. See below.

```
UPDATE p1
SET p1.Price= p1.Price * 100
FROM Products p1
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT SupplierID, SUM(Price) AS Price
            FROM Products
            GROUP BY SupplierID
            HAVING SUM(Price) = 47
           ) p2 
    ON p1.SupplierID = p2.SupplierID
```

Comment: The w3schools seems to return that there is a bit of a syntax error, will try to check it out in more detail later, I'm still not familiar with the inner join function, but I will make sure to check this out when I get there. Thanks for the effort regardless.

Comment: Okay. Good luck!